# Custom Messagebox not showing in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone application. I have to convert an image to a binary array, and I have to send this details to the back-end through web services(//some code). So this process took some time. I put this custom message box to show the saving process. but this custom message box not shown. Why is this?

Thanks in advance.

```
private CustomMessageBox cmd;//global variable

private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSignby.Text.ToString()) && MyIP.Strokes != null && MyIP.Strokes.Count > 0)
            {
                WriteableBitmap wbBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(MyIP, new TranslateTransform());
                EditableImage eiImage = new EditableImage(wbBitmap.PixelWidth, wbBitmap.PixelHeight);

                cmd = new CustomMessageBox()
                {
                    Caption = "SAVING....",
                    Message = "Please wait...."
                };
                cmd.Show();

                //some code
                //some code
                //some code
                //some code

                cmd.Dismiss();
}
}
```

Custom message box class using from Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace Microsoft.Phone.Controls
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "CaptionTextBlock", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "LeftButton", Type = typeof(ButtonBase))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "MessageTextBlock", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "RightButton", Type = typeof(ButtonBase))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "TitleTextBlock", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    public class CustomMessageBox : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFullScreenProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLeftButtonEnabledProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRightButtonEnabledProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftButtonContentProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RightButtonContentProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty;

        public CustomMessageBox();

        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public bool IsFullScreen { get; set; }
        public bool IsLeftButtonEnabled { get; set; }
        public bool IsRightButtonEnabled { get; set; }
        public object LeftButtonContent { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public object RightButtonContent { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler<DismissedEventArgs> Dismissed;
        public event EventHandler<DismissingEventArgs> Dismissing;

        public void Dismiss();
        public override void OnApplyTemplate();
        public void Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is CustomMessageBox? Can you post it code here?

Comment: using from Assembly Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let the UI thread run a bit to display the custom message box. A convenient way for that is to use the async/await keywords:

```
private async void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSignby.Text.ToString()) && MyIP.Strokes != null && MyIP.Strokes.Count > 0)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(MyIP, new TranslateTransform());
        EditableImage eiImage = new EditableImage(wbBitmap.PixelWidth, wbBitmap.PixelHeight);

        cmd = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Caption = "SAVING....",
            Message = "Please wait...."
        };
        cmd.Show();

        await Task.Delay(10);

        //some code
        //some code
        //some code
        //some code

        cmd.Dismiss();

    }
}
```